# shortcut for Django Get data and mark_safe a specific column

Tags: django

I'm just wondering if there is a shortcut to do this code?
The code get's the video data and then mark_safe the embed code.

```
videos = Video.objects.all()

    mark_safe_videos = []
    for video in videos:
        video.embed_code = mark_safe(video.embed_code)
        mark_safe_videos.append(video)
```

I'm using Django 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just add a property to the model and avoid any additional code in the view:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import mark_safe


class Video(models.Model):
    . . .

    @property
    def safe_embed(self):
        return mark_safe(self.embed_code)
```

I tend to favor the "fat model, skinny controller (view in Django)" methodology.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brandon :D I didn't know this is possible. Sorry I'm quite new to Django :D So to get the safe_embed, instead of videos.embed_code, I will have to use video.safe_embed() or just video.safe_embed?

Comment: Marking the method as a property allows you to just use `.safe_embed` in other Python code, but Django's template language doesn't care if it's a property or a method; you would call `.safe_embed` either way. `@property` isn't Django-specific, it's just part of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Brandon's answer, which I would prefer, because it exposes that functionality throughout your whole app, you can also achieve it with a list comprehension in your view:

**values_list for one field**

```
videos = [mark_safe(v) for v in Videos.objects.values_list('embed_code', flat=True)]
```

[`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) will return the requested fields as a list. Since only `embed_code` is relevant, using `flat=True` returns a one-dimensional list that we can use in the list comprehension to `mark_safe` their values into the `videos` variable.

---

*Update:* **values_list for multiple fields**

The same approach can be used for querying two or more fields.

```
# views.py
videos = [
    (v[0], mark_safe(v[1])) 
    for v in Video.objects.values_list('title', 'embed_code')
]
```

And in the template:

```
{% for video in videos %}
Title: {{ video.0 }}<br/>
Embed code: {{ video.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I agree. Often, people don't understand that they don't really need to hydrate objects when working with querysets; they just need the values, which consumes far fewer resources and can be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: There are actually two attributes for videos. The first one is the Title, then the second one is the embed_code. When I query videos, I always get the title associated with the embed_code. Is it okay to use your code when it has two columns retrieved?

Comment: @ikeMiguel yes, `values_list` will then no longer return a flat list, but a list of tuples. I've updated the answer with a snippet to fetch two (or more) fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def safe_embed_code(video):
    video.embed_code = mark_safe(video.embed_code)

mark_safe_videos = [safe_embed_code(v) for v in Video.objects.all().iterator()]
```